# Problem with Telerik RadGrid Paging and Updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, javascript, updatepanel, telerik, paging

I've set a RadGrid with Paging into a simple asp.net UpdatePanel,
and it caused a JavaScript exception.

Does anyone familiar with that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a RadAjaxManager?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Telerik grid in the same scenario and it operates normally (no js errors). Can it be that by any change you use UpdatePanel and RadAjaxManager/RadAjaxPanel at the same time? If so, only one of these should be enough to ajaxify the grid.

Dick